# how to troubleshoot an issue with CORS

Tags: http, cors

I'm trying to set up access to an Amazon S3 Bucket on an external website, so that of course means setting up CORS.  After carefully following Amazon's setup guide for CORS I am still getting this error in the Firefox console when making a request to the bucket:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ...
```

Rather than listing my CORS policy from the Amazon S3 settings and a bunch of my code, I'd like to learn, more generally, about how to diagnose a CORS issue (I'm sure I'll have similar problems in the future).  Is there some way, using the Firefox dev console (or another tool if there's a better one) to figure out exactly **why** the CORS request failed?  Perhaps the port didn't match?  Or the specific http method isn't allowed?  Or maybe there's some issue with the CORS policy not actually being sent back to the client?  It would be great if I could examine the logic that led to the error.

Comment: Try different browsers. They might give you different messages on the same error, which can point you in the right direction. In my case, Chrome gave me the right lead.